# no login prompt but getting 403 status error

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7, basic-authentication

I have a servlet setup in Tomcat 7 and have configured security-contraint and login-config to use BASIC auth.

When I attempt to go to the page I immediately get a 403 forbidden error message rather than getting the normal no BASIC-auth username/password.

What is strange is that this is setup nearly identically to another webapp which works fine.

Comment: I have a same problem, can you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I had the very same problem back in the day.
I had configured Tomcat security, it was working locally (on Windows machine) but after deploy on production server it was giving me 403 forbidden error. The thing was that production server was running Linux and Linux tomcat has different config defaults than Windows tomcat.

My solution was to define in config every possible option to match Windows defaults + my config. It worked.

Sorry for no examples but it was long ago and I just can't find the project.

Hope this helps.